# Start Activity from an OnClick event outside an Activity C#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I'll try to explain myself the best I know how. (Xamarin.Android C#)

I have a class named `PhotoAlbumAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter` where the resources of a RecyclerView containing clients images are created, assigned and configured, but this class is outside the `MainActivity: Activity` public class.

Here I have the `OnClick` method that is obviously triggered when clicking on one of the images in the RecyclerView, I use that method to save the ID of the image that was selected in some public/global variables. My problem is that I have no idea how with the results already obtained from the `OnClick` to start another Class : `Activity` where it loads the **details** of that client that I cliked on.

Try with:

```
         var Intent = new Android.Content.Intent (this, typeof (Details));
         StartActivity(Intent);
```

But it doesn't work unless it's in `MainActivity: Activity` or another Activity. The error tells me that "`StartActivity`" it does not exist in the current context.

Any ideas how to trigger my Activity `Details.cs` apart from this one?

I attach code.

```
    public class PhotoViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
            public TextView Caption { get; private set; }
            public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> listener)
                : base(itemView)
            {
                Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
                Caption = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
    
                itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.LayoutPosition);
            }
        }
    
        public class PhotoAlbumAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
        {
            public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
    
            PhotoAlbum mPhotoAlbum;
    
            public PhotoAlbumAdapter(PhotoAlbum photoAlbum)
            {
                mPhotoAlbum = photoAlbum;
            }
    
            public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                Inflate(Resource.Layout.LCardView, parent, false);
    
                PhotoViewHolder vh = new PhotoViewHolder(itemView, OnClick);
                return vh;
            }
    
            public override void
                OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
            {
                try
                {
                    PhotoViewHolder vh = holder as PhotoViewHolder;
    
                    vh.Image.SetImageBitmap(GetImageBitmapFromUrl(mPhotoAlbum[position].PhotoID));
                    vh.Caption.Text = mPhotoAlbum[position].Caption;
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                string LineErrorNumber = Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7);
            }
    
        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return mPhotoAlbum.NumPhotos; }
        }


void OnClick(int position)
            {
                try
                { 
                    VarGlobal.gIdRecyclerMaterial=(position); 
                    Busqueda.Globales.IdSeleccionado = Convert.ToInt32(mPhotoAlbum[position].TipoMaterial.Substring(2)); 


                       char c = mPhotoAlbum[position].TipoMaterial[0]; 
                        VarGlobal.gNombreMaterialR = Convert.ToString(c);
        
                        //Trigger detalles... 
//Need it here ... ********************************************************************************
                       
                        //var Intent = new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(Details));
                        //StartActivity(Intent);
    
                    
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    string LineErrorNumber = Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7);
                }
            }        
    
            private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
            {
                Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
    
                using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                    if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                    {
                        imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                    }
                }
    
                return imageBitmap;
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: you don't have any class named `Details`.

Comment: Your `ViewHolder` subclass gets passed a `View` in `OnCreateViewHolder`, and all Android views contain a context that you can use (i.e. yourViewHolderContext.StartActivity...) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.views.view.context?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9#Android_Views_View_Context

Comment: Yes I do @Jason

Comment: not in the code you posted you don't.  The file may be named `Details.cs` but that does not mean the class is named `Details`.  You can name files anything you want, that has no relation to what the class inside is named.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter shouldn't have any knowledge about the activity or context. Generally I would employ an interface to handle the callback between click events on the adapter rows and executing some action i want..

Create an interface to handle the click events between Adapter and Activity.

```
interface OnItemClickListener 
{
  void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

Add it as a parameter to your Adapters constructor and forward the callback to your ViewHolder

```
public PhotoAlbumAdapter(PhotoAlbum photoAlbum, OnItemClickListener clickListener)
{
     mPhotoAlbum = photoAlbum;
     mClickListener = clickListener;
}

public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView, OnItemClickListener listener): base(itemView)
{
     itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.LayoutPosition);
}
```

Activity extends Interface, passes clickListener to adapter at initialization and handles callback

```
public class MainActivity : OnItemClickListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        adapter = PhotoAlbumAdapter(photoAlbum, this)
    }

    ....

    protected override void onItemClick(int position)
    {
         // use item position to get some data to add to the Intent
         var Intent = new Android.Content.Intent (this, typeof (Details));
         StartActivity(Intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to replicate your answer. Probably doing something wrong. 

After creating Interface in 
'public class PhotoAlbumAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter'
 I'm getting error: "Accessibility Inconsistency...". 
Should something change due I'm using Xamarin.Android?

Comment: Sorry, i tried to write this in c# but i actually use Java and Kotlin in my day job so the syntax is probably wrong! Rather than copy and pasting you should be able to recreate the architecture here with an interface?

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much anyway. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Yes, I finally made it. What I did was to create the OnClick method but this time on the public class MainActivity : Activity instead of outside and then make a reference getting something like this: View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
            Inflate(Resource.Layout.LCardView, parent, false);

                MainActivity MyClass = new MainActivity();
                PhotoViewHolder vh = new PhotoViewHolder(itemView, MyClass.OnClick);
                return vh;

Comment: It appears as though @KennyAli comment breaks some core coding principles, the adapter shouldn't know anything about MainActivity, let alone construct one. The correct approach will be to use an interface that acts as a callback between activity and the adapter.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT You're welcome. I tried but my account was like banned or something. I'm guessing because I made mistakes when asking questions. I think it was a little hasty action tho. See ya.